# Apache htaccess URL rewrite guidance please

Tags: apache, .htaccess

aI have a site, that is mirrored across many domain names. Let's say there are 26 of them, and they are:

```
www.aaa.com
www.bbb.com
... etc ...
www.zzz.com
```

All these domains are virtual hosts that reference the same document root and hence obey the same htaccess file.

What I now want to do is turn off all of them except for three. I only want to keep:

```
www.aaa.com
www.eee.com
www.uuu.com
```

I want all the other domains to forward to www.aaa.com, including the full original URL parameters and query string.

How do I set up rewrite rules in my htaccess file such that the following 301 redirects will happen:

```
www.bbb.com/thispage/ -> www.aaa.com/thispage/
www.kkk.com -> www.aaa.com
www.eee.com (not redirected - keep processing htaccess rules below)
www.uuu.com/thispage/ (not redirected -  - keep processing htaccess rules below)
```

I hope I have made things as clear and simple as possible!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: +1 for very clearly defining your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(aaa|eee|uuu)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.aaa.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```